# Title for each plot in multiplot

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

I am doing this plot in gnuplot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U0TQ.png) \

and I don't know why there is no legend with the colors of the curves.

I am using the following these lines in the terminal,

<<<

```
mySplitX = 0.33  
unset key
set samples 200

set multiplot
set border 7        
set origin 0,0
set size mySplitX,1
set margins -1, 0, -1, -1   
set xlabel " "  
set format x "%g"
set mxtics 10
set logscale x
set xrange [1:30]
set ylabel "C_l^{TT}[{/Symbol=10 m}K^2]"
set ytics nomirror
set mytics 5
set yrange [0:15000]
plot "<(sed -n '1,30p' CMB-TT_data_Planck_cleaned.dat)" u 2:3:($3-$4):($3+$5) lc 7 pt 7 ps .5 w errorbars notitle, "explanatory00_cl.dat"  u 1:2 notitle w l lc 6, "CDM00_cl.dat" u 1:2 w l lc 4


set arrow 1 from screen mySplitX
set border 13        
set origin mySplitX,0
set size 1-mySplitX,1
set margins 0, -1, -1, -1   
set xlabel " l"
set xtics add (30)
set mxtics 5
unset logscale x
set xrange [30:2500]
unset ylabel
unset ytics
set y2tics
set my2tics 5
set format y2 ""
plot "<(sed -n '1,30p' CMB-TT_data_Planck_cleaned.dat)" u 2:3:($3-$4):($3+$5) lc 7 pt 7 ps .5 w errorbars notitle, "explanatory00_cl.dat"  u 1:2  w l lc 6 t "LCDM", "CDM00_cl.dat" u 1:2 w l lc 4 t "No CDM"
```

> > > 

as you can see I am using: title "name" in the same of the comand "plot" but I don't know why this does not work. Could anybody help me, pls?

I am looking for some like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKfGz.png)

Comment: You turned off all titles by saying `unset key`.

Comment: It does work, thank you.